# pytest-cov giving CoverageWarning but still displaying coverage report

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov

When I run `pytest` I get `CoverageWarning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected) self._warn("No data was collected.", slug="no-data-collected")` but it still displays the coverage report.

This is what is in my `pyproject.toml` file

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--cov=src/mypackage"
testpaths = [
    "tests",
]
```

Also when I replace `src/mypackage` with my packages name it gives me

```
CoverageWarning: Module mypackage was never imported. (module-not-imported)
  self.warn(f"Module {pkg} was never imported.", slug="module-not-imported")
CoverageWarning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
  self._warn("No data was collected.", slug="no-data-collected")
WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report.
CovReportWarning: Failed to generate report: No data to report.

  warnings.warn(CovReportWarning(message))
```